# How to create in polars column [curent] [this column] [value] = [previous] [this column] [value] * [current] [another column] [value]?

Tags: python-polars

I want to create this in polars:
`xL0 = 0.0 xL0 = (1 - gamma) * close + gamma * xL0[1]`

I've tried with .cumsum()/shift but it doesn't work/no idea how to do it. I don't wanna use/know lambda (unless it's faster than pandas vectorization but i don't think it is)

This is the df:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "close": [20.92, 20.7, 20.58, 20.88]
    }
)
```

This is how it should look with gamma = 0.7

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
{
    "close": [20.92, 20.7, 20.58, 20.88],
    "xL0": [6.276, 10.6032, 13.59624, 15.781368],
})

close xL0
f64 f64
20.92 6.276 (no previous xL0 value so it's just (1-0.7)*close => 0.3*20.92)
20.7 10.6032 (0.3 * 20.7 + 0.7 * 6.276)
20.58 13.59624 (0.3* 20.58 + 0.7 * 10.6032)
20.88 15.781368 (0.3* 20.88 + 0.7 * 13.59624)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample `DataFrame` and the expected output so that others can easily copy/paste some data to work quickly on your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I think it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are implementing a manual version of [ewm_mean](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.ewm_mean.html#polars.Expr.ewm_mean), with the caveat you want the first value to be zero. You can get your desired output by doing this:

```py
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"close": [0, 20.92, 20.7, 20.58, 20.88]})
>>> df
shape: (5, 1)
┌───────┐
│ close │
│ ---   │
│ f64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 0.0   │
│ 20.92 │
│ 20.7  │
│ 20.58 │
│ 20.88 │
└───────┘
>>> df.with_columns(xL0=pl.col("close").ewm_mean(alpha=0.3, adjust=False))
shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────────┐
│ close ┆ xL0       │
│ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ f64   ┆ f64       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 0.0   ┆ 0.0       │
│ 20.92 ┆ 6.276     │
│ 20.7  ┆ 10.6032   │
│ 20.58 ┆ 13.59624  │
│ 20.88 ┆ 15.781368 │
└───────┴───────────┘
```

You probably want to drop the zero though, as in your input data. The ewm_mean will automatically take a proper weighted average, rather than starting at zero.

Note that you need `adjust=False` to reproduce your desired output, but you may want to consider `adjust=True`, the default value, to correct for the starting value imbalances. See the docs linked above for more information.

Comment: Thank you!
This is what i wanted. I searched in docs but found only .cumsum() and tried to come with a solution using it. I will read the entire docs to not bother again with things already built in.